# How can I use a measure to calculate the proportion of grand total for two qualitative variables in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

my data looks like this:
`example = {("Alice", "Yellow"),("Alice", "Yellow"),("Mark", "Blue"),("Mark", "Blue"), ("Mark", "Blue"), ("Mark", "Blue"), ("Alice", "Red"), ("Mark", "Yellow"), ("Alice", "Blue")}`

In a clustered bar chart, I want to add a data label that shows the % proportion of occurrences of colors for each person, compared to the grand total.

For example, for Alice's Blue bar, I would like the bar to have a data label of 11% (since that bar shows a count of 1, and the grand total across all category counts is 9; 1/9); Marks' Blue bar should have a label of 44% (4/9), etc.

my clustered bar chart looks like this:
[image]

I think I'm having trouble understanding what my measures are doing, so I'm having difficulty creating appropriate measures to create these data labels. For instance, it's really easy for me to visualize creating a new table using "Group By" in PowerQuery. But it is challenging for me to think about how to achieve what I want with measures only/without creating a new table.

I think I have to do the following:

1. Get total count of all rows (to use as a denominator for calculating the proportions). ex: var totalcount = COUNTROWS(table)
2. Get counts across two categories -- names and colors
3. Divide counts of values against total row count. ex: var proportions = DIVIDE(counts, totalcount)

I've started with this:
`CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(example))`

which when put into a table, correctly gives me the counts of the occurrences of each color for each person.

what I can't figure out is how to use that measure to churn out a numerator and denominator that I can use in a divide function...

edit:

I've made some progress/found a solution, but I don't understand why my solution works.

```
num of occurences = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( example[Value1] ))
```

```
total cases selection only example = CALCULATE ([num of occurences], ALLSELECTED(example[Value2], example[Value1]))
```

```
proportion = DIVIDE([num of occurences], [total cases selection only example])
```

this gets me what I want because `total cases selection only example` returns the total count of occurrences across all categories, which I can use as a denominator do calculate the % proportion of each Person + Color combo compared to the grand total. But I don't understand why the ALLSELECTED function is so essential here -- if I remove it, I don't get the grand total. But I thought ALLSELECTED is a function to modify how filters are applied to the data -- I have no filters applied to my data so I'm not sure why modifying this expression results in not retrieving the grand total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's simplest form it would be:

```
% Overall = DIVIDE( COUNTROWS(example), COUNTROWS(ALL(example)) )
```

You might find this a useful read: [Power BI DAX: ALL vs. ALLSelected](https://radacad.com/power-bi-dax-all-vs-allselected)

> The `ALLSELECTED` is also a tabular function that performs very much similarly to the `ALL`. with one big difference; `ALLSELECTED` only ignores the filters coming from inside the visual itself, whereas `ALL` ignores any filters coming from anywhere in this visual or other visual on the page.